# Changes to CloudCode for Open source Parse

Tags: parse-platform

My cloud code returns this error when I run it ever since migrating to Azure. It worked fine before migrating. I do recall seeing a post about needing to change some parts of cloud code (e.g. `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();`) now that Parse has gone open source, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Here's the error:

```
2016-04-20 10:01:37.627 App Name [Error]: {
    result = Fail;
} (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)

2016-04-20 10:01:37.628 App Name {
    NSLocalizedDescription =     {
        result = Fail;
    };
    code = 141;
    error =     {
        result = Fail;
    };
    temporary = 0;
}
```

And here's my cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addFriendRelation", function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var currentUser=Parse.User.current();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    var userId = request.params.userId;

    query.get(userId,
    {   
        success: function (object)
        {
            console.log(object.objectId);

            var toUserFriend = object.relation("friends");
            toUserFriend.add(currentUser);

            object.save();

            console.log("Success");

            var jsonObject = {
                "result" : "Success"
                };

            response.success(jsonObject);
        },
        error: function (object, error)
        {

            console.log("Fail");

            var jsonObject={
                "result" : "Fail"
                };

            response.error(jsonObject);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having originates from where you have

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
```

This code is wrong.

You can however get the user that made the request using.

```
var user = request.user;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! However I still get the same error.